# Show that $m^*(E \cup F) \leq m^*(E) + m^*(F)$

Tags: real-analysis

I just started studying about outer measures and I ran into this question. Intuitively, this is true... But how would I really prove this?

I tried doing it like this but I just get stuck:

You have that $E \subset E \cup F$ and $F \subset E \cup F$, so we have that $m^*(E) \leq m^*(E \cup F)$ and $m^*(F) \leq m^*(E \cup F)$ so it follows that $m^*(E) + m^*(F) \leq 2(m^*(E \cup F))$

But I'm just stuck here... Is there any any approach I can really try based off simple outer measure properties?

Comment: Look at the definition of an outer measure. There should be a property that looks vaguely similar to what you want to prove.

Comment: Well based off the textbook I have, the outer measure of a set $E$ is the infimum of the sum of all countable covers. How would I really use that definition for help? I'm just not completely seeing it.

Comment: Ah, so you're not looking at a general outer measure but at a specific one. Then: countable covers by what sort of sets, and the sum of what is used in the infimum?

Comment: No I am looking at a general outer measure. My apologies, I guess I actually don't fully understand the definition of an outer measure then. But it says that the outer measure of $E$ if $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the infimum of the sum of the lengths of the interval.

Comment: That would be a specific outer measure on the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, the outer measure associated to the Lebesgue measure. For general outer measures, [cf. wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure#Formal_definitions), where it's a direct consequence of the definition. For the specific case, how are countable covers of $E$, $F$, and $E\cup F$ related?

Comment: I think it would be wise to include the definition of outer measure you're using in the question (i.e. not just comments) - the proof very much depends on this, as other equivalent definitions would make this trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you defined for any set $S$ the set of countable covers $C_S$ of countable covers of $S$ constructed from intervals. If you define $\ell(c)$ for some cover $c$ of $S$ to be the sum of all the lengths of the intervals in $c$, then you could define the outer measure as
$$\mu(S)=\inf\{\ell(c):c\in C_S\}.$$
So, we are interested in $\mu(E)$, $\mu(F)$, and $\mu(E\cup F$). How should we relate them? Well, we should relate $C_E$, $C_F$, and $C_{E\cup F}$ - that is, the countable covers of those sets. In particular, you can prove that:
$$C_{E\cup F}=\{c_1\cup c_2:c_1\in C_E \text{ and } c_2\in C_F\}$$
and that $\ell(c_1\cup c_2)\leq \ell(c_1)+\ell(c_2)$. This implies the desired result.